# Euler graph and cycles

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that the graph $G$ is an Euler graph if and only if the set of its edges
can be divided into separate non-empty subsets, each of which induces simple cycle in $G$.

Comment: What part of this are you having trouble with?

Comment: I have got a problem when in G is only one cycle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each connected component of a graph $G$ is Eulerian if and only if the edges can be partitioned into disjoint sets, each of which induces a simple cycle in $G$.

Proof by induction on the number of edges.
Assume $G$ has $n\ge 0$ edges and the statement holds for all graphs with $<n$ edges.

If $G$ has more than one connected component, the claim holds for each (smaller) component, hence for all of $G$.
Hence we now assume that $G$ is connected.
The case $n=0$ is trivial, hence we may assume $n>0$.

$\Rightarrow$: Consider an Euler cycle $v_0v_1v_2\ldots v_n$ with $v_0=v_n$. Consider all $(i,j)$ with $0\le i<j\le n$ and $v_i=v_j$.
Such pairs exist because $v_0=v_n$ (and $n>0$!). Select $(i,j)$ among these pairs such that $j-i$ is minimized.
Then $v_iv_{i+1}\ldots v_j$ is a simple cycle $\gamma$ and $v_0\ldots v_iv_{j+1}\ldots v_n$ is an Euler cycle of the graph $G':=G-\gamma$.
By induction, $G'$ can be partitioned into disjoint cycles. Together with $\gamma$ we obtain a partitioning of $G$ into disjoint cycles.

$\Leftarrow$: Assume $G$ can be partitioned into disjoint cycles. Since $n>0$, there must be at least one cycle in this partitioning.
If there is exactly one cycle, it is automatically an Euler cycle and we are done.
Otherwise, select one cycle $\gamma=v_0v_1\ldots v_k$ (with $k>0$ and $v_k=v_0$). Then we obtain a partitioning of $G-\gamma$ into disjoint cycles, hence by induction each component of $G-\gamma$ is Euler.
Also, $\gamma$ shares at least one vertex with each connected component of $G-\gamma$.
Construct an Euler cycle of $G$ as follows: Start with $\gamma$ and extend it as follows:
If $G'$ is a connected component of $G-\gamma$, select $v\in G'$ that occurs in $\gamma$ (and hence also in the Euler cycle as constructed so far) and replace the first occurance of $v$ in the cycle as constructed so far by an Euler cycle of $G'$ that begins and ends in $v$.
After processing all components $G'$ like this, we obtain an Euler cycle of $G$.